# Error in connecting R to MySQL running on Amazon ec2 Ubuntu machine

Tags: mysql, r, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have recently configured MySQL on my Amazon EC2 Ubuntu machine. I am trying to connect MySQL db to RStudio running on the same machine. I am using the R package `RMySQL` for the same.

My R-code:

```
library(dbConnect)
library(RMySQL)
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user1', password='pass1', dbname='db1', host='http://ec2-*********.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/')
```

**The error message:**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.9/d3.min.js"></script>
    Error in mysqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
      RS-DBI driver: (Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown MySQL server host 'http://ec2-52-24-185-205.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/' (2)

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: try **host='localhost'** if both rstudio and mysql are on the same machine.

Comment: Yep don't be doing public hostname else you need a few tweaks

Comment: I also tried **host='localhost'**, still getting the same error!

Comment: in the host you dont need to add the port? 3306?

Comment: @paul Yeah, both port and host-ip are not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to connect on an Ubuntu machine to a MySQL database using the following:

```
library("RMySQL")

mySqlCreds <- list(dbhostname = "YourHostIP",
               dbname   = "YourDB",
               username = "YourUserName",
               pass = "YourPassword",
               port = 1111
                 )

drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
dbConnect(drv, host=mySqlCreds$dbhostname, dbname=mySqlCreds$dbname, 
        user=mySqlCreds$username, password=mySqlCreds$pass, port = mySqlCreds$port)
```

Where of course the port is whichever port you or your DBA has specified...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

I finally resolved the issue. I had to configure my user credentials first in mysql.

**MySQL query:**

```
create user 'user1'@'my-ec2-public-ip';
set password for 'user1'@'my-ec2-public-ip' = PASSWORD('pass1');
grant all on *.* to 'user1'@'my-ec2-public-ip';
```

**R-code:**

```
library(RMySQL)
#establishing connection
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user1', password='pass1', dbname='db1')
```

Rightly quoted by grubjesic and Drew Pierce I should not mention the host, as mysql db and rstudio are running on the same machine.